# In Node.js short arrays handled differently than longer ones

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

Notice the difference between the way names and names2 is handled.  Why am I getting this difference? How can I make names behave like names2?

BTW, I get the same behavior in Firefox.

```
> names
[
  'Liam',     'Noah',
  'Oliver',   'Elijah',
  'William',  'James',
  'Benjamin', 'Lucas',
  'Olivia',   'Emma',
  'Ava',      'Charlotte',
  'Sophia',   'Amelia',
  'Isabella', 'Mia'
]
> names2
[ 'Noah', 'Oliver', 'Sophia', 'Mia' ]
> names .map((n)=>n+'\n') .reduce((x,y)=>x+y,'') 
'Liam\n' +
  'Noah\n' +
  'Oliver\n' +
  'Elijah\n' +
  'William\n' +
  'James\n' +
  'Benjamin\n' +
  'Lucas\n' +
  'Olivia\n' +
  'Emma\n' +
  'Ava\n' +
  'Charlotte\n' +
  'Sophia\n' +
  'Amelia\n' +
  'Isabella\n' +
  'Mia\n'
> names2 .map((n)=>n+'\n') .reduce((x,y)=>x+y,'') 
'Noah\nOliver\nSophia\nMia\n'
>
```

Comment: It seems to just be the way Node.js shows the results to make things more readable. Is this causing you an issue? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Yeah, those should be the same. The other array is a lot bigger, so the console just shows it like that.

Answer (score 0):

This is just how long strings are displayed.

For example, try typing this in a node console:

```js
"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\nbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb"
```

it will show this output:

```js
'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\n' +
  'bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb'
```

Answer (score -1):

The first part of my question was the important part.  The answer I now think is that this behavior is a optimization in some Javascript engines to provide lazy evaluation of `reduce` for large arrays.

The second question can now be rephrased as "how to force that lazy evaluation to run to completion the way `console.log` does?"  An answer to that would be interesting but I don't need it as I am capable of writing my own `reduce` function.

Comment: The arrays aren't processed in a different way, their output is simply _represented in a different way_. Node's REPL takes a value (a short string, long string, integer, Buffer, etc) and uses `util.inspect` to _["print the value out in the best way possible given the different types."](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/internal/util/inspect.js#L284)_. Also note [the description in the docs](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#utilinspectobject-options): _"The output of util.inspect may change at any time and should not be depended upon programmatically."_

Comment: I like this answer better than mine.